# File Not Found ng2-page-scroll

Tags: angular

I try to use Library ng2-page-scroll but follow their step it show file not found ng2-page-scroll. 
     it's seem it was error in systemjs.config anyone know how to fix that problem?

Install ng2-page-scroll

```
npm install ng2-page-scroll --save
```

In app.module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {Ng2SimplePageScrollModule} from "ng2-simple-page-scroll";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ,Ng2SimplePageScrollModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In systemjs.config

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'ng2-simple-page-scroll/ng2-simple-page-scroll': 'ng2-simple-page-scroll/bundles/ng2-simple-page-scroll.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app : {defaultExtension: 'js', main: './main.js'},
      rxjs: {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Here is the Result File not found
[ng2-page-scroll Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZADGj.png)

Comment: By configuring SystemJS to find it. Figure out where it is on disk, and map the path.

Comment: Thank @AluanHaddad I try to map it already but it still not work. 

map = {
     'ng2-simple-page-scroll/ng2-simple-page-scroll': 'ng2-simple-page-scroll/bundles/ng2-simple-page-scroll.umd.js',
}

any ideas to fix that problem??

Here is the link of that library

https://github.com/Nolanus/ng2-page-scroll

Comment: doesn't it  need to be `'ng2-simple-page-scroll/ng2-simple-page-scroll': 'npm:ng2-simple-page-scroll/bundles/ng2-simple-page-scroll.umd.j‌​s'`? If that doesn't work, post your config. There is not enough information to answer otherwise.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I already edit it to get more information. could you help to check it. thanks before hand.

Comment: Don't forgot to accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
'ng2-simple-page-scroll/ng2-simple-page-scroll': 'ng2-simple-page-scroll/bundles/ng2-simple-page-scroll.umd.js',
```

with the line

```
'ng2-simple-page-scroll': 'npm:ng2-simple-page-scroll/bundles/ng2-simple-page-scroll.umd.js',
```

Why do you need to do this?

Well first of all you have written

```
import {Ng2SimplePageScrollModule} from "ng2-simple-page-scroll";
```

So the module specifier `"ng2-simple-page-scroll"` must correspond to a `map` or `package` entry in your `systemjs.config.js`

And secondly, the paths entry of your `systemjs.config.js`

```
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
```

indicates that the prefix `npm:` points to the `node_modules` directory. This is further evidenced by all other packages in the `map` having that prefix.

Comment: @SouengKimmeng glad to have helped :) don't forget to vote for / choose the answer if it worked for you ;)

Comment: Yeah, Angular 2 is one of the most complex frameworks you could choose to invest in. It is incredibly complex in terms of both API surface and in terms of how it accomplishes even the most basic tasks. SystemJS is simple by comparison, although still complex, but has nothing to do with Angular 2. Frameworks like React + (reflux/redux/whatever the flux) and Aurelia are much simpler to get started with. I personally have yet to see the relative complexity of Angular 2 pay off for anyone... And I've put Angular 2 code into production and maintained it.

Comment: It's also tough because for many people it is their first exposure to TypeScript. TypeScript is very easy to learn, if you know JavaScript. But if you only look at TypeScript through Angular 2 tutorials, you will probably never understand it.

Comment: Holding me hostage.